# Looking for a manga reader for the original iPad hardware

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, applications, performance

I'm currently using the app [icomic](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icomic-comic-reader/id297328082?mt=8) with my 1st generation iPad and have used it for probably 2 years.

It's decent, but it struggles to display very large images well. Specifically, the images become pixelated and unreadable.

I wish to read more of the very large image comics there are rendered unreadable with this app.

Is this a limitation inherent to the hardware of the iPad (e.g. not enough ram or GPU) or perhaps limited by the app's design? I can't confirm hardware being the cause, in fact I feel like it's the app rather than the device. Other apps like Safari do well with detailed large pictures given enough time to download and render them.d

Are there better manga/comic readers for viewing large images on the 1st gen iPad?

Edit: The majority of manga I'm reading works fine. I actually really like the app. But some images just don't work.

Example of an image that doesn't display correctly: please try opening [this image](http://f.cl.ly/items/3T3P3R1k3M013f083G2E/Girl_the_Wild%27s_c00_p01.jpg) in your recommended comic app and see if it's readable.

Comment: Are you looking to read specific manga? Or do you want to be able to read common comic file types?

Comment: @SamE iComic is pretty good for common comic file types. I'm only looking to resolve 1 issue with the large image. But in general, yes I'm looking for a reader not a specific manga.

Answer (score 1):

Try "Stanza" or "CloudReaders"...

Answer (score 1):

I used to use Stanza, but a few months ago I discovered **ComicFlow** it's free and it is *very* well done. I haven't had any issues with the wide assortment of comics I've uploaded to it.

I use both CBZ and CBR formats.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Thanks for your answer! Can you please add information about the software you mentioned? Thank you!

Comment: ComicFlow doesn't resolve my problem, I actually think iComic is a lot better, thanks for the suggestion though.